# How to create new Servlet and JSP project on Ubuntu?

Tags: tomcat, java, jsp, servlet

I've installed Tomcat 7, javaservlet 3.0 and openjdk 7. I read that I need to install Eclipse and Web Tool platform (from eclipse) but I can't find it. I install few packages from eclipse there is no `dynamic web project` that I need to create. I found only `static web project` (but it's for static html pages).

How can I create servlet or JSP project? Do I need Eclipse to create one (I'm sure not)? If not then how to create using just any editor. I only know that I need to create WEB-INF/web.xml file but where? I install examples but I can't find them on disk (I've found index.html in /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT but no trace of examples).

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure you can find a lot of JSP tutorials like http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/ on the Internet of you search for it!

I always make my JSP pages and servlets using NetBeans IDE. It's so simple and powerful. Give it a try.

Comment: Tutorals don't exmplain how to setup the app, they start from writing java code. And I'll prefer not to use IDE so I can learn how to setup the app by myself.